# Kotlin file changes result in Redeclaration error

Tags: android, kotlin

Every change to a kotlin file results in a Redeclaration error when building. The only way around it is by cleaning the project and then rebuilding. There are no other files in the project with the same name as the files I am editing.

I have tried:

- Renaming the class I have been working on
- Upgrading and downgrading the version of kotlin, gradle and kotlin plugin in Android Studio
- Using beta Android Studio
- Reordering the plugins in my gradle file

The current build is using:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0
```

Example code that will cause the error. If I build without the `addedThisLine` it works as its the first build. Then when I edit the file in anyway it will cause the error below.

```
package beagle.com

class ErrorFragment {

    val hello = "Hello"

    init {
        var goodbye = "goodbye"
        var addedThisLine = "When this line is added I get error"
    }
}
```

Error I get

[image: Redeclaration Error]

This happens in every kotlin file in my project, the code I posted above is the most basic file. As you can see it points to the name of the class for the error.

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`?

Comment: yeah, same result as cleaning. After a change I get the error again

Comment: Take a look at this github page, it may help you: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/168

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be eclipse related. My issue is happening with Android Studio. I looked for the settings the link suggested but Android Studio didn't seem to have equivalents

Comment: Try downloading latest **Kotlin plugin bundle** in Android Studio *(It might be 1.3.40 or something)* Then Re-Import the project and check again. It might solve the issue.

Comment: I had some strange issues once too. When I deleted the `build`-(and/or `out`-?)folder, it started working again as expected with no further problems... maybe that works for you too...

Comment: Create a new, clean project that does not have this problem. Then move your files and configuration one by one over to the new project. Either the problem will be fixed, or you will know what specific file/configuration that causes the problem.

Comment: Any solution?? I am facing the same issue while running the unit tests and if tests failed I need to clean the project which again run gradle clean and then run the unit tests again..!! not finding any specific solution around it. Error: > Task :module:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin <PathToTestClass.kt>Redeclaration: <TestClassName>

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this ? I have the same problem. I can get around it by deleting files under build/<module>/tmp/kotlin-classes but it is still annoying. The issue seems to only arise on Linux and might be to do with using a softlink for the module code in my case.

Comment: @user1785227 It sounds like a bug to me, and the question is what part is responsible for it. If a similar/same bug happens with Eclipse+Maven, instead of Android Studio+gradle here, the common factor seems to be Kotlin or maybe Kotlin plugins. I have skimmed a bit here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT?q=redeclaration , but did not find anything with the quick skim. If you want to, it might make sense for you to report the bug/issue there.

Comment: I've boiled down my issue to be specifically on Linux, when a kotlin class is referenced through a directory softlink, the compiler doesn't read the link correctly in some part of the process. This works OK on Windows (rather annoyingly as I've just switched to Linux :)). Will raise a bug on the Jetbrains site and see if I get any luck.

Answer (score 41):

just clean project and rebuild your project again

Comment: The solution to all problems

Comment: ./gradlew clean

Comment: This worked for me. The god of all things android and eclipse.

Comment: I think I got this error when I renamed some packages to remove some capital letters. Cleaning the project and rerunning it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR**: Check your directories have the exact same name as they appear in `settings.gradle`.

Worth to mention: MacOS is not always case sensitive and that can lead to weird problems.

---

I think I find a solution: **Case sensitive stuff**.

In my case I'm using modules, let's just call the modules: `moduleA`, `moduleB`

In `settings.gradle` I have: `include ':ModuleA', 'moduleB'` but the directories at file system level are: `moduleA/` and `moduleB/`

This seems weird and should not work but the first run always works, then the next ones will fail until project is cleaned.

I decided to keep things consistent and rename the directories as the `settings.gradle` lists them, even when in AndroidStudio they appear with the name listed in `settings.gradle`. This also helped to cleanup things because git has a configuration under `.git/config` which states to ignore the case sensitive stuff.

So, check the case of your directories vs. how they are listed in `settings.gradle`.

After renaming stuff and cleaning with gradle everything worked as before.

Comment: happens to me using camelcase in the packagename

Comment: Oh my, i had this issue for MONTHS and could not figure it out. This solved it. You sir are a true hero! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade `kotlin` and `gradle` version then

Try to `Run` this may this will help

```
./gradlew clean
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*
```

or

Try to add the following to your gradle.build file if not added

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue,

```
./gradlew clean
```

was the solution for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using Kotlin 1.8 and SQLDelight 1.5.3. I incremented the sqldelight version to 1.5.5, then issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

1. Build > Clean Project
2. Build > Rebuild Project
3. Run

Answer (score 1):

1.clean and rebuild

if this don't work its for conflict of classes names !

Just **Rename** or change path of class ,  because  you have **same name of class** in **one package** !

Answer (score 1):

if Clean Project And Rebuild Not working . Try sync project. That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I have created same data class twice in same package was causing the error
**Redeclaration: Results** .
try to not create Kotlin class with same name in one package

Answer (score 0):

As of jul 2020 you will get this Redeclaration error when there is an already existing class with the same name, so either you have to rename or move to a different package.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin compiler can fail in MacOS and Linux environments, when there is another Java file with the same name in the path.
Renaming file can fix the issue as @sana says

[Similar issue on JetBrains issue-tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44441)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do that, change the version of kotlin and try again

```
buildscript {
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
}
```